# Will entire Class component or render() be executed each time state is updated?

Tags: reactjs

I read from the documents that component is Re-rendered each time state is updated. Does it mean entire class execution or only render()?

```
Class Sample extends component {
    render() {
      <Footer onSelect = (item) => this.setState(item1:item) />
    }
}
```

If the state is updated as per above example, what would be the further execution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you update a State in a Component it will trigger more than the render() function. In order it will call:

`shouldComponentUpdate()`

`componentWillUpdate()`

`render()`

`componentDidUpdate()`

If you are passing that state as property to a child Component, this action will update it too, calling the `componentWillReceiveProps()` and all the above functions in that child Component, so it will be re-rendered too.

You can read a good article [here](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/) about the React Lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

The `setState()` function will run a chain of a series of function in this order:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() > componentWillUpdate() > render() > componentDidUpdate()
```

In the case of the supplied component only the `render()` function will run, updating any of the components related with the state.

Comment: In that case can I assume that 'Footer' component will not be executed when render() function Re-rendered?

Comment: It will re-render your footer too as you have set the state. Here is an article about what setState does: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

Comment: -if the 'Footer' executes once again, then state will be updated once again. Then won't it be a recursive process?

Comment: It will only be rendered again when you call the onSelect property from the Footer component.

Comment: @Loonger-Thank you